# Requests setting cookies in cookieJar including subdomains

Tags: node.js, cookies, node-request

I have a bunch of cookies in JSON format. They're the result of exporting cookies from a plugin called [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en).

I'm attempting to parse the JSON cookie array and add them to a cookiejar. I do this like so:

```
JSONCookies.forEach(cookie => {
    let extensions = [
        'session=true',
        'sameSite=no_restriction'
    ];

    cookies.push(new ToughCookie.Cookie({
        key: cookie.name,
        value: cookie.value,
        secure: cookie.secure || false,
        path: cookie.path,
        httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly || false,
        extensions: extensions
    }));

    // Set the uid property of object with users ID
    if(cookie.name === 'c_user') {
        this.uid = cookie.value;
    }
})
```

I add them to request's cookiejar:

```
cookies.forEach(function(cookie) {
    cookieJar.setCookie(cookie, 'https://facebook.com', (err, cookie) => {
        if(err) {
            reject(new Error(err));
            return;
        }
    })
})
```

... And this works fine. I can make requests to Facebook and pull data from our business groups.

But, many requests on Facebook use a subdomain. Such as `upload.facebook.com`. This doesn't work. Obviously because I'm missing the `domain` from the cookie.

So, I create the tough-cookie and add `domain: '.facebook.com'`. Except now when I make a request it fails with an error:

```
Error: Cookie not in this host's domain. Cookie:facebook.com Request:null
```

How am I able to set the cookies in the cookiejar to work across sub domains? Is it possible?

The documentation isn't very good, and I've been unable to find out how to do this. I think it has something to do with the URL passed into `setCookie`. I've attempted to change that to different variations to no avail.

Comment: @CBroe wrong. I've been selling software that helps group admins manage spam on their groups for the past year. Such actions can not be performed with the API as the Group endpoint is limited. Facebook have been aware of my software for 8 months as I work closely with Facebook's security team reporting bugs. They do not have an issue with it as it benefits the owners of groups and does something the API doesn't support.

Comment: @CBroe https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php?hc_location=ufi ... see number 2. Our company has permission from Facebook. Anyone can file for permission by completing the following form: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. The solution is to do this:

```
cookies.push(new ToughCookie.Cookie({
    domain: 'facebook.com'
    key: cookie.name,
    value: cookie.value,
    secure: cookie.secure || false,
    path: cookie.path,
    httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly || false,
    extensions: extensions
}));
```

The leading `.` in `.facebook.com` isn't required. This was discussed on the [tough-cookie github issue](https://github.com/SalesforceEng/tough-cookie/issues/26) too.